# Why does the scheduler kill my shuffling algorithm?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, shuffle

I came up with this algorithm for shuffling random users to another users. (for secret santa game) But when I start async process for shuffling at given time it stops by the 5th user. Any ideas why?

My service for the algorithm and starting it :

```
public class GitfteeServiceImpl implements GifteeService{
@Autowired
private  UserRepository userRepository;

private final ScheduledExecutorService shufflingScheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

@Override
public void setGifteeToAll() {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
    List<User> usersGiftees = userRepository.findAll();
    List<Long> userIds = usersGiftees.stream().map(User::getUserId).collect(Collectors.toList());
    log.info(users.toString());
    for(User u : users){
        User giftee = getGifteeForOne(u, usersGiftees,userIds);
        userIds.remove(giftee.getUserId());
        usersGiftees.remove(giftee);
    }
}

private User getGifteeForOne(User user, List<User> users, List<Long> ids) {
    Long randomId = getRandomId(ids);
    User giftee = userRepository.findByUserId(randomId);

    while (giftee == null || !users.contains(giftee) || Objects.equals(user.getUserId(), randomId)){
        randomId = getRandomId(ids);
        giftee = userRepository.findByUserId(randomId);
    }

    user.setGiftee(giftee);
    userRepository.save(user);
    return giftee;
}

private Long getRandomId(List<Long> ids) {
    Collections.shuffle(ids);
    return ids.get(0);
}

@Override
public void scheduleShuffling(LocalDateTime gameDuration) {
    Runnable scheduleShufflingTask = this::setGifteeToAll;
    Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), gameDuration);
    shufflingScheduler.schedule(scheduleShufflingTask, duration.getSeconds(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

}

This is my controller:

```
public class AdminController {

@Autowired
GifteeService gifteeService;

@PostMapping("/start_date")
public void hi(@RequestBody LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    LocalDateTime aDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 17, 22, 39, 50);
    gifteeService.scheduleShuffling(aDateTime);

}
```

Comment: How do you know that is the scheduler?

Comment: Well, the method is working without the scheduler, I tested it.

Comment: Why is your LocalDateTime hardcoded to 17th January?

Comment: Again it was for a test - yesterday was 17th January.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after deep debugging I found out that actually my algorithm is incorrect, and it is normal to be killed by the scheduler. here is the change I did :

```
private User getGifteeForOne(User user, List<User> users, List<Long> ids) {
Long randomId = getRandomId(ids);
User giftee = userRepository.findByUserId(randomId);

//The line that was incorrect
while (giftee == null || users.contains(giftee) || Objects.equals(user.getUserId(), randomId)){
    randomId = getRandomId(ids);
    giftee = userRepository.findByUserId(randomId);
}

user.setGiftee(giftee);
userRepository.save(user);
return giftee;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you found your issue.